# No repetition of values in list (C#)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, isolatedstorage, listboxitem, windows-phone-silverlight

I created a favorite list box where the user can save text from `Textblock` in `MainPage.xaml`

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column= "0" HorizontalAlignment= "Left" VerticalAlignment= "Top" >
    < Button x:Name= "FavoriteButton" FontFamily= "Segoe MDL2 Assets"
            Content= "&#xE006;" BorderBrush= "Transparent" FontSize= "28"
            Foreground= "{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
            Style= "{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" Click= "FavoriteButton_Click" />
</ StackPanel >

<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column= "2" HorizontalAlignment= "Left" VerticalAlignment= "Top" >
    < Button x:Name= "FavoriteListButton" FontFamily= "Segoe MDL2 Assets"
            Content= "&#xEA55;" BorderBrush= "Transparent" FontSize= "28"
            Foreground= "{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
            Style= "{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" Click= "FavoriteListButton_Click" />
</ StackPanel >
```

`C#`

```
    private void FavoriteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        listobj.Add(new MyData { AnswerName = AnswerTextBlock.Text });


        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = Settings1.OpenFile("MyStoreItems", FileMode.Create))
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyDataList));
            serializer.WriteObject(fileStream, listobj);

        }
    }

    private void FavoriteListButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(FavoriteListBox.Visibility.Equals(Visibility.Collapsed))
        {
            FavoriteListBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else if(FavoriteListBox.Visibility.Equals(Visibility.Visible))
        {
            FavoriteListBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }           
    }
```

and Listbox

xaml

```
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">                
            <ListBox x:Name="FavoriteListBox" Visibility="Collapsed" 
                     SelectionChanged="FavoriteListBox_SelectionChanged"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                     VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="1"
                     Background="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
                     Height="300" Width="250">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Visibility="Visible" x:Name="FavoriteListBoxTextBlock"  
                                   FontSize="35" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding AnswerName}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
```

`C#`

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    IsolatedStorageFile Settings1 = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    MyDataList listobj = new MyDataList();

    public MainPage()

    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;

        if (Settings1.FileExists("MyStoreItems"))
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = Settings1.OpenFile("MyStoreItems", FileMode.Open))
            {
                DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyDataList));
                listobj = (MyDataList)serializer.ReadObject(fileStream);

            }
        }


        FavoriteListBox.ItemsSource = listobj;//binding isolated storage list data



    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Settings1.FileExists("MyStoreItems"))//loaded previous items into list
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = Settings1.OpenFile("MyStoreItems", FileMode.Open))
            {
                DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyDataList));
                listobj = (MyDataList)serializer.ReadObject(fileStream);

            }
        }
    }

    public class MyData
    {
        public string AnswerName { get; set; }            
    }
    public class MyDataList : ObservableCollection<MyData> //for storing mydata class items with type of list
    {

    }
```

All text of `Textbox` which show some text go to isolated storage on favorite button click. but it copies same text again even if that text already exist in the list, so I want when ever user click on favorite button it should check first if text already exist in the list or not, If exist then it should replace or should not copy again. so how to do this.

Comment: AnswerTextBlock is textblock where some text will be visible and goto favorite list

Comment: or also answer details about , how to check whether text exist or not in list box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for duplicates quite easily using a LINQ `Any` query at the beginning of the `FavoriteButton_Click` method:

```cs
private void FavoriteButton_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    //check if there is any item with the same text
    //in which case do not continue
    if ( listobj.Any( l => l.AnswerName == AnswerTextBlock.Text ) ) return;

    listobj.Add( new MyData { AnswerName = AnswerTextBlock.Text } );


    using ( IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = Settings1.OpenFile( "MyStoreItems", FileMode.Create ) )
    {
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer( typeof( MyDataList ) );
        serializer.WriteObject( fileStream, listobj );

    }
}
```

Comment: can i remove that item from list if already exist in place of prevent it to copy again.
it is better to remove that item if already exist in list for my app

Comment: Well, if it is the exact same entry, I don't see a reason to remove instead of just leaving the original one there :-)

Comment: But it is possible to remove if already exist using same button

Comment: or how to remove particular item from list box on another (remove) button click

Comment: Well, you can add another button and then call `listobj.Remove( AnswerTextBlock.Text )` instead of `Add` in a new handler.

Comment: thanks, now i have enough enough information about list box
thanks for your help,.... and i will happy if you provide me answer of future question. your answers always work.. great.......... ;) :)

Comment: may be i will need help regarding listbox item selection changed event i will post separate  question for this. :)

Comment: Could you post it as a question? What error does it show?

Comment: okay, but it normally red underlined when i simply write this code

 
listobj.Remove( AnswerTextBlock.Text );

Comment: If you hover your mouse over the red line, what error is there shown?

Comment: cannot convert from 'string' to 'XeroQuiz.MainPage.MyData'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128634/discussion-between-martin-zikmund-and-shubham-sahu).

Comment: I see now, you can do it like this: `lsitobj.Remove( listobj.FirstOrDefault( l => l.AnswerName == AnswerTextBlock.Text ) )`

Comment: ha ha now its work thanks..... :) i will post new question for list box item selection , hope you will help... thanks :)..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40845803/automatically-filter-order-listbox-items-windows-phone