# Automatically Sort ListBox Items (A to Z or 1 to 9 serial wise)

Tags: c#, sorting, windows-phone-8.1, listboxitems, windows-phone-silverlight

I have a `ListBox` on my WP 8.1 Silverlight app that looks like this:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">                
    <ListBox x:Name="FavoriteListBox" Visibility="Collapsed" 
             SelectionChanged="FavoriteListBox_SelectionChanged"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="1"
             Background="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
             Height="300" Width="250">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Visibility="Visible" x:Name="FavoriteListBoxTextBlock"  
                       FontSize="35" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding AnswerName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

In my `ListBox` the items should look like this:

1. item1
2. item2
3. to 15.....

However currently it is not in the order of 1,2,3,4... Instead it is in order of when the item is added.

I want the `ListBox` items to serialize automatically. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort a list or array before serializing, you can use two different solutions.

Arrays have a static `Array.Sort` method, that sorts the items of the array in-place (sorts the contents of the instance itself).

For lists and other collections you can use LINQ's `OrderBy` extension method.

```
var sortedList = list.OrderBy( 
    item => item.PropertyToOrderBy )
    .ToList();
```

Note, that the original `list` is left intact, the result of the `ToList()` extension method is a new instance.

Comment: can you provide ore details

Comment: i am work with listbox first time so please provide in details, how to do that

Comment: Basically it is not related to the listbox itself, because you have to sort the data which are displayed in the listbox. The code I have posted you can use befor you serialize the data so that they are stored in the file in sorted order. And if you put the data from the sortedList in listbox, they will be sorted in the UI as well.

Comment: list - the name 'list' does no exist in current context

Comment: List is just a name of the variable containing you data. If you post the code, I could tell you which is the right one

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40627267/no-repetition-of-values-in-list-c this question containts whole code releated to list box

Comment: In that case just replace list by listobj :-)

Comment: it show an error show in this two images https://1drv.ms/f/s!Ahppl6XCmlXfkaRTpGSXsMSRn8rjkA

Comment: Yes, you also need to replace the PropertyToOrderBy by AnswerName

Comment: You have to use the sortedList variable - or you can just replace "var sortedList" with "listobj" in my code

Comment: I will have to see the screen shots with the error message again

Comment: I don't understand, we haven't changed anything to do with favorites. Apparently you need to mark the _favorites field as static, but I don't understand how It could have worked before

Comment: If you could update your question or post a new question with all the code that you now have, it would help, otherwise I don't really understand what is going on... :-(

Comment: okay i am also very confused, i will post new question..   : |! ,Thank you for taking the time to  my question