# Tapped event should not fire when holdding event perform (UWP)

Tags: c#, uwp

Because Hold And Tap Event is not available in UWP so i am using Tapped And Holding event in UWP.

for Windows phone 8 apps i am using tap hand hold event for button. where when i hold a button tap event is not fire.

but in UWP i tried Click and Tapped event but both fires when i hold button.

**please suggest me other method where other event should not fire when i hold a button**
Holding Event here is necessary, suggest me alternate of Tapped and click event because these event fires when i hold and release a button

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
       <Button Name="BackwardButton" 
               FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE26C;"
               FontSize="30" Background="Transparent"
               Tapped="BackwardButton_Tapped" Holding="BackwardButton_Holding"
               PointerExited="BackwardButton_PointerExited"/></StackPanel>



<TextBlock Name="txtBox1"  FontSize="18"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
```

**C#**

```
private static int i;
private void BackwardButton_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    i++;

    txtBox1.Text = i.ToString();
}


private int a = 10;
private void BackwardButton_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{
     BackwardButton.Content = "\xE100";
     try
     {
         a++;
         txtBox1.Text = a.ToString();
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
         //Exception(ex);
     }
}



private void BackwardButton_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{           
    BackwardButton.Content = "\xE26C";            
}
```

Solutions i already tried-
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e386e2e8-0312-4b1e-8eea-9522db83d632/click-and-tapped-event-should-not-fire-when-holding-event-perform?forum=wpdevelop

And solution tried on windows 8 but hold and tap event not available in UWP
[Click Event should not trigger when hold event perform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41074596/click-event-should-not-trigger-when-hold-event-perform)

Comment: Actually you will need to show more of your code. I can't replicate this.

Comment: @JustinXL Okay i added more code

Comment: Okay xaml added

Comment: When I *long hold* on the button, only the `Holding` event fires... What did I miss?

Comment: But when you release the button tapped event also fires, but when i use same thing win 8 phone hold and tap event, tap event isn't fires when i hold and release a button

Comment: Are you sure you are doing a Hold? The tapped event is not fired on my end.

Comment: How ?. In my end, when i hold the button it increment the value by 1 and as soon as i release the button it increment the value by 10

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150922/discussion-between-justin-xl-and-shubham-sahu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the `Holding` event will fire twice. First time is in `HoldingState.Started` state and second in `HoldingState.Completed`. All you have to do is wrap your logic within the following `if` statement

```
private void BackwardButton_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.HoldingState == Windows.UI.Input.HoldingState.Started)
    {
        ...
    }
```

I'd recommend you to start using breakpoints to work out issues like this though. It should be fairly straight forward to figure out the `Tapped` event is never called during holding by putting a breakpoint at

```
txtBox1.Text = i.ToString();
```

Hope this helps.